# Get value from database

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I've been trying to get a value from txt1(jtextfield) which is an id in my database. But it keep saying java.lang.NullPointerException. Here is the code:

```
public void harga()
{

   try {
        stat = con.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT harga from obat WHERE ID = '"+ Integer.valueOf(txt1.getText())+"'";
        stat.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSet rs = stat.getResultSet();
        while (rs.next()) {
            int harga = rs.getInt("harga");
            //String nama = rs.getString("nama");
            System.out.println(harga);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: at line 142, the String query line

Comment: and how `txt1` is initialized?

Comment: JTextField txt1 = new JTextField();

Comment: in that case, there is no value set in `txt1`, make sure there is some value before you query db.

Answer (score 1):

First @Sagar seems to be right as it is not ensured that there is a castable value in `txt1`. To ensure that you should add an ChangeListener for `txt1`.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html

Second it's bad practice to concat the query together, especially if the query parameters are coming from an UI. The reason behind this is that you are opening yourself to SQL injections. Use instead `PreparedStatements`:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Happy coding and welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you said that txt1 is initialized as

```
JTextField txt1 = new JTextField();
```

This seems wrong: txt1 should be a variable of the class, but you wrote a local variable that doesn't exists outside that method. Try this

```
private JTextField txt1; //Below the class declaration "public Class ..."

txt1 = new JTextField(); //Instead of the line you wrote to initialize txt1
```

Comment: i've tried this, but still got an error :(

Comment: Which error exactly? If you still have the same error probably there is a problem in the way you pass txt1 to the function that executes the query